# Validation com Internationalization no Laravel 5.3 apresentando erro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou criando uma aplicação onde tenho que validar os dados enviados para o banco (óbvio), porém, estou tendo como resposta o seguinte erro:

> ErrorException in FileLoader.php line 109:
>
> Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string

Para que vocês possam entender melhor vou apresentar meu código:

routes/web.php

```
...
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard/{locale}/'], function($locale) {

    if (empty($locale)) {
        $locale = 'pt-BR';
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    ...
    Route::get('api/add', 'ApiController@addApi');
    Route::post('api/add', 'ApiController@storeApi');

    ...
}
```

Exemplo de URL: `/dashboard/pt-BR/api/add`

app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php

```
public function storeApi(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        $this->rules, 
        $this->messages
    )->validate(); // Por padrão, em caso de erro, ele retornaria para o form com os erros.

    $api = $this->apiRepository->model()->create($request->all());
    
    // $this->locale = 'pt-BR' - É recuperado por um middleware...
    if ($api) {
        return redirect()->to(
            'dashboard/' . $this->locale .
            '/api/add-accounting/' . $api['id']
        );
    }
}
```

**Uma coisa que observei**

Eu acessei o caminho apresentado no erro, sendo ele:

```
\path\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader.php
Linha: 109
```

E o método é esse:

```
protected function loadPath($path, $locale, $group)
{
    if ($this->files->exists($full = "{$path}/{$locale}/{$group}.php")) {
        return $this->files->getRequire($full);
    }

    return [];
}
```

Se eu colocar um `dd()` em cada parâmetro, tenho:

```
$path = 'path\resources\lang'
$locale = Router {#24 ▼
              #events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
              #container: Application {#3 ▶}
              #routes: RouteCollection {#26 ▶}
              #current: Route {#230 ▶}
              #currentRequest: Request {#40 ▶}
              #middleware: array:6 [▶]
              #middlewareGroups: array:2 [▶]
              +middlewarePriority: array:5 [▶]
              #binders: array:1 [▶]
              #patterns: []
              #groupStack: []
          }
$group = 'validation'
```

Eu particularmente acho que o problema deve estar no `$locale` mas não consegui identificar precisamente qual o erro, pois forcei o mesmo para `$locale = "pt-BR"` e o erro muda para:

> ErrorException in Translator.php line 273:
>
> Illegal offset type

Imaginei que pudesse ser erro exatamente nos arquivos de tradução, porém, validei o mesmo e também está tudo certo, porém, para qualquer dúvida, seguem os mesmos no [github](https://github.com/developerewt/laravel-5.3-intl-pt-BR).

Comment: Já tentou usar esse pacote aqui ? https://packagist.org/packages/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: Onde a intl entra? ela está habilitada?

Comment: Sim, intl está habilitado e, se eu remover a validação, tudo funciona. O problema está na hora que tento validar os campos e retorna um erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em como você define seu `Route::group`. Esse método é diferente dos que são utilizados com `Route::get`, `Route::post` e afins.

Embora ele também receba uma função anônima, o primeiro argumento recebido é um objeto do tipo `Illuminate\Routing\Router` (repare no que retorna no seu `dd`).

Algo que pode te ajudar com o que você quer fazer é utilizar o [Sub-domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups):

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{locale}.myapp.com', 'prefix' => 'dashboard/'], function () {

    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($locale, $id) {
        // Ao acessar pt-br.myapp.com/dashboard/user/1
        echo $locale; // pt-br
    });

});
```

Isso implica em mudar um pouco a estrutura das suas rotas, mas ao meu ver é uma maneira mais simples para alcançar o que você quer.

A partir dai você pode definir o `app()->setLocale()` a partir de um [*middleware* global](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#global-middleware) por exemplo.